# Multiply by a cell formula

Tags: vba, excel

I am calculating the next excel table in VBA and leave the results as values because of a volume of data. But then I have to multiply these range by 1 or 0 depending on a column. 
The problem is that I don't want to multiply by 0 becouse I gonna lose my data and have to recalculate it (I don't want it). 
So, after my macro I get a next table, for example:

```
var.1   var.2   var.3
 0       0       0     
 167     92      549   
 159     87      621   
 143     95      594   
 124     61      463   
 0       0       0     
 5       12      75
```

in a `Range("A2:C9")`.

In a `Range("A1:C1")` i gonna have a 1 or 0 values that will be changing so i need my `Range("A2:C9")` to be like:

```
     var.1   var.2   var.3
     =0*A$1    =0*B$1   =0*C$1   
     =167*A$1  =92*B$1   =549*C$1   
...
```

Is it possible to do with a macro? Thank's

[image: Table i get after calculating macro]

And I would like to get

[image]

Comment: So in A1:C1 you'll either have 1 or 0 and you don't want to recalculate the table if you multiply by 0? Why multiply at all if it's just 1 or 0 and you don't want a change? Can you show us a screenshot of the data?

Comment: There you have. This way if I change a value in B1 to 0 the values in column B will become 0, changing B1 to 1 I will get my initial values and don't lose the data

Comment: I could do another table, referencing every cell to the original and multiplying by another cell, but I would like to know if it is possible the solution as I am asking

Comment: It would be great to see a comment after "-1"

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what I would do here is first copy the original data to another sheet or set of columns so that it is always preserved. Then use this formula:

```
=IF($A$1 = 0, 0,E3)
```

Instead of writing the cell E3 reference the data that you copied.

Comment: If I did 2 tables, I would prefer to write ``"=B3*B$1"``, rather then your solution.

Comment: Yeah, I understand you, thank's! But It is good to know different options and in my case, where a table is pretty huge, I'll be glad to find a way to don't duplicate it